# Python import module give blank output

Tags: python, import

I have a file named task.py with the below code

```
def add(a,b):
    c = a+b
    return c
```

and another file named inputs.py with the below code

```
import task
a = task.add(2,2)
print(a)
```

When I run this code, it shows a black output with no errors. Both the files are present under the same directory.

Can anyone confirm why it does not show any outputs?

Comment: Cannot reproduce your problem. Seems to be working for me.

Answer (score 0):

This worked after i had the Python file and Pycharm file in under C directory.

Answer (score 0):

Python scripts must be in current working directory. You can check CWD using following code:

```
import os
os.getcwd()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is specific to your system.

I have tried and it worked fine for me

Try the following :

- Running again
- delete pycache
- run by pressing run button in your code editor
- run by `python inputs.py`